# Characterizing isometry invariant functions

Tags: operator-theory, isometries

I am trying to understand functions invariant under isometries better. In particular functions with two inputs. I.e.
$$
C(x,y) = C(\phi x, \phi y)
$$
for any isometry $\phi$.

> The motivation are isotropic random functions (random fields, random processes). $C$ is the covariance function. I can expand on this if asked, but it is not necessary to understand the rest

### Lemma (Characterizing isometries in Hilbertspaces)

Let $H$ be a Hilbertspace (it might be necessary to assume it is finite - I don't care at the moment) and let $x_1,\dots x_n, y_1,\dots, y_n\in H$. Then

1. > $\|x_i\| = \|y_i\|$ and $\|x_i - x_j\| = \|y_i - y_j\|$ for all $i,j$

   is equivalent to

   > there exists a *linear* isometry $\phi$ such that $\phi x_i = y_i$
2. > $\|x_i - x_j\| = \|y_i - y_j\|$ for all $i,j$

   is equivalent to

   > there exists an isometry $\phi$ such that $\phi (x_i) = y_i$.

##### Proof

1. Due to the polarization formula, the scalar products are also invariant. Applying Gram-Schmidt to both $x_1,\dots, x_n$ and $y_1,\dots, y_n$ therefore results in the same basis representations. Then we simply map orthonormal basis to orthonormal basis and check the requirement.
2. immediately follows from 1. by shifting $x_1$ to be the origin in the domain and $y_1$ to be the origin in the image. The new points are $\tilde{x}_j = x_j - x_1$ and similarly for $y$. These satisfy 1. so we can apply it. Shifts are isometries.

### Corollary (Characterizing isometry invariant functions)

Any function $C$ which is invariant to all isometries can be written in the form
$$
C(x,y) = k(\|x-y\|)
$$

> If the function $C$ is a covariance function, the underlying random function is said to be "isotropic"

And any function $C$ which is invariant to all *linear* isometries can be written in the form
$$
C(x,y) = k(\|x\|, \|y\|, \|x-y\|) \overset{\text{Polarization}}= \tilde{k}(\|x\|, \|y\|, \langle x, y\rangle).
$$

##### Proof

Use the Lemma above with $n=2$ and select representants to define $k$.

### Question: Isometries w.r.t. the operator norm

I am now interested in matrices. It is obviously possible to view $n\times n$ matrices as members of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and apply the theory above. But the issue is, that this allows isometries which completely destroy the structure of the linear map $A$. So I am interested in a characterization of the isometries w.r.t the operator norm. And then a characterization of the functions

$$
C(A,B) = C(\phi A, \phi B)
$$
for (linear) isometries w.r.t the operator norm and where $A$, $B$ are matrices.

I am not even sure yet, how the set of isometries of the op norm looks. For linear isometries $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$

$$
\phi_2\circ A \circ \phi_1
$$
is a linear isometry in the op norm sense. Are all isometries w.r.t. the op norm of this form? I would expect that this is a characterization task, someone has already done.